# Error using Ninject and Web API 2 with route attribute in controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, ninject

I have a web API 2 project that implements Ninject. It works fine if my controllers do not use Route attributes but, if I use them, the application returns  the following exception: "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'AccountsController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."

Works fine

```
public IHttpActionResult get()
{
    var entities = EntityService.getAll();
    return Ok(entities);
}
```

Do not work

```
[Route("user")]
public IHttpActionResult get()
{
    var entities = EntityService.getAll();
    return Ok(entities);
}
```

I have the following packages installed

```
Ninject version="3.2.0.0"
Ninject.Extensions.ContextPreservation version="3.2.0.0" 
Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope version="3.2.0.0"
Ninject.Web.Common version="3.2.0.0"
Ninject.Web.Common.OwinHost version="3.2.3.0" 
Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost version="3.2.3.0"
Ninject.Web.WebApi version="3.2.4.0"
Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost version="3.2.4.0"
Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebHost
```

My NintextWebCommon class is

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(ProperdiAPI.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(ProperdiAPI.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace ProperdiAPI.App_Start
{
    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;
    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Common;
using System;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Http;

    public static class NinjectWebCommon
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start()
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();

            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();
                RegisterServices(kernel);

                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }

        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<IEntityService>().To<EntityService>().InRequestScope();
        }
    }
}
```

BaseApiController

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
    {
        private IEntityService entitysService;

        public BaseApiController(IEntityService entityService)
        {
            this.entityService = entityService;
        }
         protected IEntityService EntitysService
         {
             get
             {
                return this.entityService;
             }
         }
        protected IHttpActionResult GetErrorResult(IdentityResult result)
        {
            if (result == null)
            {
                return InternalServerError();
            }

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                if (result.Errors != null)
                {
                    foreach (string error in result.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
                    }
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return BadRequest();
                }

                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
[RoutePrefix("api/accounts")]
public class AccountsController : BaseApiController
{
    public AccountsController(IEntityService entityService)
    :base(entityService)
    {
    }
    [HttpGet]
    //[Route("user")]
    public IHttpActionResult get()
    {
        var entities = EntityService .getAll();
        return Ok(entities);
    }
}
```

I've tried a lot of things, like building a custom resolver and scope, installing an old ninject version and so on, but nothing works.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Could you add the controller class constructor to the question as well?

Comment: I've just added the controller class and the baseApiController I use. Thanks!

Comment: If you find this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195159/ninject-error-in-webapi-2-1-make-sure-that-the-controller-has-a-parameterless

Comment: Thanks @MukeshModhvadiya for your response. I tried it but it didn't work. Still getting the same error. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install plugin `Ninject.WebApi.DependencyResolver` and add this code after call to `RegisterServices(kernel);`:

```
 System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Ninject.WebApi.DependencyResolver.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixed the error and now my controllers are working! Thanks again!